# Python 3: Numpy 3d array to Pandas dataframe with 1st dimension values as columns and rows/cols position paired in one column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

As the long title hints, I have an array of shape [n,m,z] and I want to turn it into a Pandas dataframe with the first column being an array of row and col position (2nd and 3rd dimension) and the next 13 columns being the value as from 1st dimension, leading to a DataFrame of (m*z)Xn. I have been reading the other examples but I haven't found any with pivoting one dimension to columns.

For example, for an array of shape [3,2,4]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rand_int = np.random.randint(10,90,(3,2,4))
print(rand_int)

[[[57 76 30 34]
  [21 70 10 51]]

 [[73 67 55 51]
  [78 38 50 76]]

 [[89 58 47 35]
  [45 11 61 18]]]
```

I want it to return as

```
Pair   Col1   Col2   Col3
[0,0]   57    73      89
[0,1]   76    67      58
[0,2]   30    55      47
...
[1,3]   51    76      18
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may loop in `m` and `z` dimension to retrieve value.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 3
m = 2
z = 4

rand_int = np.random.randint(10, 90, (n,m,z))

datas = [[[57, 76, 30, 34],
          [21, 70, 10, 51]],
         [[73, 67, 55, 51],
          [78, 38, 50, 76]],
         [[89, 58, 47, 35],
          [45, 11, 61, 18]]]

res = []

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(z):
        res.append([[i, j]] + [data[i][j] for data in datas])

df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Pair', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
```

```py
print(df)

     Pair  Col1  Col2  Col3
0  [0, 0]    57    73    89
1  [0, 1]    76    67    58
2  [0, 2]    30    55    47
3  [0, 3]    34    51    35
4  [1, 0]    21    78    45
5  [1, 1]    70    38    11
6  [1, 2]    10    50    61
7  [1, 3]    51    76    18
```

Comment: This is a great answer, simple in its perfection and perfect in its simplicity. I also wanted the number of DataFrame columns to be dynamic and not pre-defined but I can work great with this. Thank you very much for your answer. If noone else answers the next couple of days, I will also accept it.